# RabbitMQ configuration for Wildfly

Tags: rabbitmq, wildfly-8

Does anyone successfully replace HornetQ by RabbitMQ in Wildfly 8?

I'm trying to use our enterprise messaging system and extract the logic of messaging from our base app server to separate the concern between messaging and our core product.

I looked on the web and did not find anything useful as how to change the standalone.xml

Any help, even if the answer is - it is not possible - would be great.

Thank you

Comment: I wonder if this could work: https://github.com/leogsilva/rabbitmq-resource-adapter

Comment: Did you find solution? And what does the link say? @KoheiNozaki

Comment: @Nabin Unfortunately not yet. The link is a RabbitMQ adapter for WildFly. I haven't tried it yet either.

Comment: I did not find a solution yet. But we decided to move to WildFly 10, so hopefully it will be easier since the messaging system has changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bounty is about to expire and I don't see help until now. So, I am answering as per my experience.

From question:

> Any help, even if the answer is - it is not possible - would be great.

Don't know, but we don't need to do that. I have found a work around for that.

 Answer is 
**RUN RABBITMQ's OWN SERVER**

I followed [this](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-debian.html) link to install it on ubuntu server. Then I read [these](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html) awesome and simple tutorials. Those six tutorials were great base to start with.

I am now integrating the project with my Java EE project which runs on Wildfly 9 server.

Best of luck to anyone who ends up here. Any constructive edits and answers are welcomed.

Comment: were you able to integrate RabbitMQ's client into Wildfly such that your apps were able to use JNDI lookups to retrieve the connection?  Where/how did you have to configure Rabbit's client jars?

Comment: This was long back ago. I don't remember it. But I think it was under settings of Wildfly server. I accessed it from browser